# Problema con la longitud de un diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios, jupyter

Importo a una DataFrame las siguientes cotizaciones.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override() # <== that's all it takes :-)

# download dataframe
datos = pdr.get_data_yahoo("SPY", start="2000-01-01", end="2021-04-30")
datos.shape[0]
```

La sentencia `datos.shape[0]` me devuelve el número de registros en el DataFrame, que en este caso son 5366.
A continuación convierto el DataFrame a un diccionario e intento que me devuelva el número de elementos en el diccionario.

```
data = datos.to_dict()
len(data)
```

Me devuelve 6, lo cual es incorrecto. ¿Cuál es mi fallo?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: cual es tu DataFrame??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Me devuelve 6, lo cual es incorrecto. ¿Cuál es mi fallo?. Agradeceré ayuda.

El fallo es de comprensión, el resultado devuelto es **correcto**, cuando utilizas `len()` sobre un diccionario te devuelve el **número de claves** que tiene dicho diccionario (que corresponden a las columnas de tu `DataFrame`) y tienes seis columnas/claves.

### Bonus

Si quieres trabajar sobre una tabla de datos, (haciendo conteos, medias, extrayendo longitudes) te recomiendo quedarte con el formato `DataFrame` ya que un diccionario te será más complicado de trabajar.

Solo utilizaría el diccionario en situaciones de restricciones de memoria o tiempo.